# Android Studio - Unable to change the logcat timestamp from EDT timezone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using 'Android Studio' on a Windows 7 PC.  The logcat timestamps are showing up in EDT timezone.

Is it possible to change it to my PC timezone, which is in IST?

I connect a couple of devices and both have date/time set in IST timezone.

Note: From my initial bit of research, I guess this problem is specific to windows users.  I might be wrong here though.

Answer (score -1):

The below steps worked for me:

> 1. Open Android Studio in PC
> 2. Connect the device
> 3. Uncheck the option on device to set the time automatically
> 4. Manually change the timezone to something else
> 5. Update the timezone to correct one now

The above steps trigger something that changes the logcat timestamp.

**Issue rootcause:**  I was connecting to genymotion emulated devices initially.  Those had EDT timezones which reflected in my logcat.  This did not change automatically when I connected real devices (with IST timezone).

Comment: Has this worked for anyone? Doesn't seem to change the logcat timestamps for me

Comment: nope doesn't do anything

Comment: @CaptainCrunch: sorry that it didn't work in your case.  I am the one who posted the question.  I didn't get any response and I found the steps in this answer after a bit of googling.  As it worked for me, i thought i will share it in the forum.  It is about 4 years now, so i guess a lot could have changed and these steps are no more valid.  I am tempted to delete the answer but would leave it there for now as it might give an idea about a possible root cause.